# Uncaught (in promise) CustomPouchError

Tags: javascript, pouchdb

I am creating an anime app and I have problem when I tried to access a particular anime supposed to present me a list of chapters of that anime And then when I click on a particular chapter, I will present the streaming section of the video.

```
// npm packages
import React from 'react';
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

// my packages
import db from '../../db';

//access to all chapter of the series
export default withRouter(({series, history}) => {
  const openSeriesPage = async () => {
    // but you can use a location instead
    const location = {
      pathname: `/series${series._id}`,
      state: series,
    };

    const doc = await db.current.get('series');
    const update = {
      _id: 'series',
      data: series,
    };
    if (doc) {
      update._rev = doc._rev;
    }
    await db.current.put(update);

    history.push(location); // error in this particular part!!
  };

  return (
    <div className="tile is-parent is-3">
      <div className="tile is-child">
        <div className="card" onClick={openSeriesPage}>
          <div className="card-image">
            <figure className="image">
              <img src={series.image} alt={series.title} />
            </figure>
          </div>
          <div className="card-content">
            <div className="media">
              <div className="media-content">
                <p className="title is-4">{series.title}</p>
                <p className="subtitle is-6">Episodes: {series.count}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
});
```

This is the error

> Uncaught (in promise) CustomPouchError {status: 404, name: "not_found", message: "missing", error: true, reason: "missing"…} history.push(location);

Comment: Oh, sorry, it's my first time to post. I will have it in consideration next time

Comment: You should remove the image and post your code in **this** question or it will be closed as not being [mcve], and possibly downvoted, resulting in a question ban

Comment: Uncaught (in promise) CustomPouchError {status: 404, name: "not_found", message: "missing", error: true, reason: "missing"…}   
                                                                                      history.push(location);

Comment: Please post the db code too.

Comment: Fix the problem with a try {} catch () {}